# CDH 5 installation on Ubuntu 16 (oracle VM)

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to install CDH 5 on Ubuntu and following the below for instructions.

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_cdh5_install.html

I am trying to install CDH 5 without cloudera manager i.e Unmanaged installation.

I am getting an error in Step 3: Install CDH 5 with YARN

When I run the command **sudo apt-get install hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager**.

I get error:

```
namenode1@namenode1:~$ sudo apt-get install hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
```

> [sudo] password for namenode1:
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager"

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to install any other packages from that repo?
I would say either the Cloudera repository is incorrect (unlikely) or it hasn't been added to your machine correctly.
Maybe you used the repo from the incorrect version or forgot to refresh it running "update"

Please make sure you follow the steps:

```
sudo wget 'https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cdh/cloudera.list' \ -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudera.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Hey  ,Thanks for the reply, I did that step already, Infact, All the steps before this step , have been done successfully...Nope, I was not able to install any other package as well, it gave me same error for others too.

Comment: Anyone faced this issue? could you please help

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue.

As the error sugest its not able to find the pacakages in the repository for some reasons, so I added them  from Unbuntu Software and updates .

I read below 2 post to understand things and after adding the repository from GUI the command worked.

[Post 1 , Explantion by Pandya](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt)
    - read explanation by pandya.

[Post 2 - Adding extra reporsitory](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

- read "Adding extra repositories " this helped me resolve the issue.
  (** I skipped step 9 "In a terminal enter the "key command" as I did not know what this is , but this did not matter at least in my case.)

Thanks all for you help!

Regards,
RVS